# Confused by split(), indexOf() and regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, split, indexof

I have written a simple game in Java that can be initialized with a string. In order to set up the board, my program separates the string by newlines or vertical bars. The game works perfectly if the string uses vertical bars, but does not work when the string uses newlines. Here is the code that i'm having issues with:

```
    String rowSeparator, indexChar;
    if(board.indexOf("|") >= 0) {
        rowSeparator = "\\|";
        indexChar = "|";
    } else {
        rowSeparator = "\\n";
        indexChar = "\n";
    }
    columns = board.indexOf(indexChar); //this one is set to -1 when the error occurs (\n instead of vertical bars)
    rows = board.split(rowSeparator).length; //this one is set to 1
```

Here is an example of a string that works:

```
"*###########*|#           #|#  ... ...  #|#  *$$ $.$  #|# $*+$ $*$$ #|#  *$$ $.$  #|#  ...  .   #|#           #|*###########*"
```

If I replace the vertical bars with "\n", it doesn't return the right values for columns and rows. Could someone help me understand what i'm doing wrong?

EDIT: I don't know if this is relevant, but when I run the debugger, the value of the string that uses newlines is "*###########*\\n#           #\\n#  ... ...  #\\n#  *$$ $.$  #\\n# $*+$ $*$$ #\\n#  *$$ $.$  #\\n#  ...  .   #\\n#           #\\n*###########*". It has two backslashes, instead of one (which is how I entered it). Could this be a problem?

Comment: don't use `\\n` use only `\n`

Comment: "doesn't return the right values for columns and rows" what values does it return? It's not clear whether your code comments pertain to the "\n" separated example.

Comment: character literals should be in single quotes, '\n' != "\n" ?

Comment: TheLostMind I tried that, but it still gives me an error.

Comment: It shouldn't.. What error do you get?

Comment: NegativeArraySizeException. The same as before with \\n. It sets the columns and rows to -1 and 1, exactly the same as before.

Comment: indexOf returns -1 if it can't find the thing you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, `columns` has the value -1 and `rows` has the value 1 instead of what you would expect.

`indexOf(x)` returns -1 if it can't find x. You're looking for the newline in the wrong way

The value 1 for rows indicates that no split was performed, so the character you want to split on also is not what it should be.

This is a backslash problem. If you have a String like `String n = "\n"`, it will be treated as the special value *newline*. If you then have another String which contains `\n` as literal character sequence, *newline* won't match.

For the regex expression where you are escaping the special chars, again you have to escape backslashes.

Long things short, it should work if you double all backslashes.